# format specifier for sprintf doesn't work

Tags: c, string, epoch

so I am trying to form a string out of epochtime to use it as a filename, I have previouly struggled with printintg epochtime and I got the answer for the correct casting and format specifier: which is this :

```
printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)epochdate);
```

now this is a simple example for the code that so far doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EXTENSION ".txt"

int main(void) 
{
    struct tm t;
    time_t t_of_day;
    char* filename = NULL;
    FILE *fp=NULL;

    t.tm_year = 2019-1900;  // Year - 1900
    t.tm_mon = 7;           // Month, where 0 = jan
    t.tm_mday = 8;          // Day of the month
    t.tm_hour = 16;
    t.tm_min = 11;
    t.tm_sec = 42;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;       //dst unknown
    t_of_day = mktime(&t);
    long test = (long)t_of_day;
    
    sprintf("filename", "%ld"EXTENSON,test);
    printf("%s", filename);
    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
    }
    
}
```

again the idea is to get epoch time and use it with an extension(here ".txt") to form a string to use in a filename.
I have tried casting to long double and using "%ld" . I tried casting to uintmax_t and using "%ju" both dont work!! any ideas?

Comment: Oh, that's really sneaky with `extension` being a macro. That's really not the way to do it when you have `sprintf` literally right there. Do `"%ld.txt"` to make it clear what you're doing.

Comment: You also cannot `sprintf` to a const char like `"filename"`. You need to write to a buffer. Did you mean `sprintf(filename, "%ld.txt", test)`? If so, `filename` is `NULL`, so you need to allocate memory first. Suggestion: `char filename[PATH_MAX]`.

Comment: @thart line is what i am asking about. it is wrong and my question is how to correct it. the syntaxe isnt wrong. but more the format specifier.

Comment: @Barmar Just saw that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to allocate memory for a path name of sufficient length. A safe default is:

```
char filename[PATH_MAX];
```

The rest will work out if used correctly, like:

```
sprintf(filename, "%ld.txt", test);
```

Don't get all sneaky with things like the `extension` macro:

- Generally macros are in `ALL_CAPS` so we know they're macros
- Using macros with string concatenation like that in the middle of your code looks like a syntax error.
- `sprintf` is perfectly capable of concatenating, there's no need to resort to a dastardly approach like that.

Note that if you do this inadvertently:

```
sprintf("filename", "%ld.txt", test);
```

Then `sprintf` writes to the memory occupied by the static string `"filename"` which is completely unrelated to the `filename` variable. It's also a bad idea since that could easily overflow.

Comment: How about `sprintf("filename, "%ld%s", test, extension);`

Comment: @Barmar I'd argue the macro just gets in the way and should be eliminated, but that's also a good approach.

Comment: @Barmar extension isn't a variable. it's a macro.

Comment: @BeNicePlz So? It expands to a string, you can use that string as an argument to `sprintf()`.

Comment: "Using macros with string concatenation like that in the middle of your code looks like a syntax error." --> Like `"Print a 32-bit type " PRId32 "\n"` or are you advocating not using std library macros for format specifiers?  The "Don't get all sneaky with things like the extension macro" is taking away from OP's good idea for abstraction the extension.  Embedding it in the format as suggested here makes for higher maintenance code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If you're using a macro, you should at least label it like it is a macro, e.g. all-caps, and use it in a way that's unambiguous. The lack of space here makes it look like a typo.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think you're misunderstanding me. I think the space helps with clarity, so I'm with the C spec style all the way. The original code in this question had it in the `"..."macro` style which I think looks like a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you can do simply following below example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRBUFFER 100

int main()
{   
    int num = 10;
    char arr[] = "filename";
    char extension[] = ".txt";
    char newfile[STRBUFFER] = {0};
    
    sprintf(newfile,"%s_%d%s", arr,num,extension);
    printf("newfile = %s\n", newfile);
    
    return 0;
}
```